# Как правильно перенести SVN репозиторий, с проблемами в структуре, c sourceforge.net на GIT (github)?

Tags: git, github, svn, git-svn

Всем привет!
В общем есть такая проблема. Есть [SVN репа проекта на sourceforge](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/osfree/code/) с любовно разложенными граблями и есть желание как можно более незаметно, по коммитам, и как можно более правильно, перенести его на гитхаб. Текущая структура не сложная -- транк, одна ветка, один тэг, всё по стандартным путям. Проблема в том, что до ревизии 774 ничего этого не было, даже транка! То-есть, по сути, транк проекта лежал непосредственно в корне репозитория, потом опомнились, но грабли остались. Итак, хочется: Перенести проект на GitHub с сохранением всех коммитов, тэгов и веток так, как буд-то досадного недоразумения в виде лежащих в корне файлов проекта никогда не было.

```
git svn clone https://svn.code.sf.net/p/osfree/code/ root
```

и

```
git svn clone https://svn.code.sf.net/p/osfree/code/trunk/ trunk
```

Дают репы с разным набором коммитов, что логично. Но что и как правильно делать дальше с этим всем, как-то не придумывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться особенностью команды `svn fetch`: если привязанная к svn ветка уже существует - она всегда продолжает ее независимо от предистории.

Для начала надо получить самые ранние коммиты. Проще всего сделать это через `git svn clone` (как вы уже сделали). Кстати, выполнение этой команды можно попытаться прервать как только вы увидите что пошли коммиты содержащие папку trunk - они не понадобятся.

Дальше лезем в `.git/config` и находим конфигурацию git-svn, где будет написано что-то вроде вот такого:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn.code.sf.net/p/osfree/code/
    fetch = :refs/remotes/svn
```

Сюда надо добавить описание ветки trunk:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn.code.sf.net/p/osfree/code/
    #fetch = :refs/remotes/svn
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn-trunk
```

Первую строчку fetch я закомментировал потому что она более не понадобится.

Теперь надо найти последний коммит, в котором еще не было переноса кода в trunk - и записать его хеш в файл `.git/refs/remotes/svn-trunk`. Только будьте готовы к тому, что если вы сделаете это Блокнотом на винде - он создаст файл с именем `svn-trunk.txt` вместо `svn-trunk`. Лучше воспользоваться командой `echo`:

```
$ echo хеш-коммита > .git/refs/remotes/svn-trunk
```

Теперь можно запустить `fetch`:

```
$ git svn fetch
```

Если все сделано правильно - эта команда затянет оставшиеся коммиты, содержащиеся в транке.

Если нужно затянуть еще и ветки (branches) - то же самое проделывается для каждой. Только не забудьте вручную найти правильную точку ветвления для каждой - автоматическое из определение в `git svn fetch` работает отвратительно!

---

Альтернативный способ - через `git filter-branch`. Но он сложнее.

Comment: О! Вроде помогает! Делал так: `git svn clone -r1:1 --ignore-paths="^[^/]+/(?:branches|tags)" --preserve-empty-dirs --placeholder-filename=dummy.txt -A svn-git_users.txt svn://localhost osfree-temp` (зеркало svn на локале) Потом соответственно два последовательных fetch с редактированием файлов между ними: `git svn fetch -r2:773` и `git svn fetch` HEAD остался на первом коммите, поэтому `git reset --hard e4a54bd9ebdf2018d95263660dde26c3b8c2b3af` (Хэш реального в SVN HEAD) Теперь-бы понять как формируются имена для бранчей и тэгов, но это уже мелочи.